# WPF: add blur effect on button when mouse is on that button-MouseEnter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make a simple animation - when mouse cursor is on button I want to add blur effect on that button.

So far I have this.:

```
<Button x:Name="button_Copy" Content="Leaderboard" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="311,217,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="139" Height="34" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFE2DBDB" IsHitTestVisible="True" Click="button_Copy_Click">    
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
             <BeginStoryboard>
                 <Storyboard>    
                     <DoubleAnimation From="10" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.1" 
                                Storyboard.TargetName="blurEffect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Radius"/>    
                 </Storyboard>
             </BeginStoryboard>
         </EventTrigger>
     </Button.Triggers>                
 </Button>
```

Build is succesfull, but when I take cursor over that button program immediately crashes... Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: We are missing the `blurEffect` definition here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you probably took your example from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/72976004-495e-46f9-aaa7-ba66d5fdae66/animation-for-blur-effect-in-wpf-xaml?forum=wpf).

You are missing the object `BlurEffect` as shown within the `TextBox` item as below:

```
<TextBlock Name="TxtSample" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="This is a sample and first test freetext">
    <TextBlock.Effect>
        <BlurEffect Radius="10" x:Name="blurEffect"/>
    </TextBlock.Effect>
</TextBlock>
```